# Button with click event in info window

Tags: javascript, google-maps, ionic-framework

I have added a click event to a button inside info window content. But the code that should run after click event executes even without clicking the button. When the map is loaded, console.log("Hi") click event code is automatically executed. I can't figure out what exactly is triggering click event of the button.

```
getPostsForMarker(defaultlat, defaultlng) {
    this.searchService.getAllPostForMarker(defaultlat, defaultlng).subscribe(
      data => {
        this.postMarker = data;

        var resultArray = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.postMarker.length; i++) {
          console.log(this.postMarker[i]);
          console.log(this.postMarker[i].Latitude);
          this.locations = [
            resultArray[i] = { lat: this.postMarker[i].Latitude, lng: this.postMarker[i].Longitude }
          ]
        }

        console.log(resultArray);
        console.log("Zoom map to");
        console.log(resultArray[0]);

        const options = {
          center: resultArray[0],
          zoom: 12
        }

        this.map = new google.maps.Map(this.mapRef.nativeElement, options);

        //to add marker in the map
        var marker = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < resultArray.length; i++) {
          marker[i] = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: resultArray[i],
            map: this.map
          });
          //to add info window
          marker[i].addListener('click', (event) => {
            infowindow[i].open(this.map, marker[i])
          })

        }

        // contents to display in info window
        var contentString = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.postMarker.length; i++) {
          contentString[i] =
            '<b>Space Type:</b> ' + this.postMarker[i].Space.SpaceTypeName +
            '<br><b>Address:</b> ' + this.postMarker[i].Address +
            '<br><b>Purpose:</b> ' + this.postMarker[i].Suitable.SuitableForType +
            '<br><b>Price:&nbsp;</b>' + this.postMarker[i].Price +
            '<br><strong>No of available rooms:&nbsp;</strong>' + this.postMarker[i].NoOfRooms +
            '<br>' +
             '<input type="button" value="View Details"  id="detailbtn" onclick="'+console.log("Hi")+'"/>'
            ;
        }


        //to add info window in the map
        var infowindow = [];
        for (let i = 0; i < this.postMarker.length; i++) {
          infowindow[i] = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
            content: contentString[i]
          });
        }

      });



  }
```

Comment: Please take a look at the rendered HTML. The console.log is called when running the script, and the result of the logging (`undefined`) is assigned to the onclick attribute value.

Comment: You should change addListener to addEventListener